# how to track the sql services in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2 and I wanted to know when the sql services has been started and services related things in SSMS.

Does anybody know about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stored procedure xp_servicecontrol is your friend. Example just run on my SMSS:

```
EXEC xp_servicecontrol N'querystate',N'MSSQLServer'

Current Service State
--------------------
1 Running
```

[This link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2036/monitor-start-and-stop-sql-server-services-using-xpservicecontrol/) on MSQLTips website will point out into the right direction and even has some explicit code where to begin testing and create a windows batch job to keep track of the services.

Edited:
According to your comment then the following SELECT clause will answer your needs:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_server_services
```

It gives you name of the service, status, last startup time, path of where the file is located and some more. [Check MSDN for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204542%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: it is just telling us whether service is running or stopped but we need to know about the service name, updated date etc. can you please help me to get this..